# In batch, how do you parse % as plain text?

Tags: batch-file

I need to parse % as text, instead of a variable. How do I do this?

I'm trying to parse this line in particular... (SENSITIVE INFORMATION HAS BEEN REDACTED)

```
start /wait srcds.exe -console -game garrysmod +maxplayers 32 +map %map% +exec server.cfg +gamemode %app% -insecure -tickrate 33 +rcon_password "[REDACTED]" +sv_loadingurl "www.friendshipisgaming.net/fig/index.php?mapname=%m&steamid=%s&servername=%servername%" +host_workshop_collection [REDACTED] -authkey [REDACTED]
```

%m and %s need to be parsed to srcds.exe as %m and %s. Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should double the percent sign: `%%m`